# Dumping a unconscious enemy to the water, counts as a kill?

Tags: dishonored

I just finished a mission, and i dont remember killing anyone, but i threw 3 bodies on the water.

At the end of the mission, i ended up getting "3 kills"

So, dumping a unconscious guard/enemy to the water, counts as a kill ?

Comment: ...can you think of a reason why it wouldn't?

Comment: Yes, drowning someone counts as killing them O.o